# how to store WKInterfaceTimer value in a variable on button click in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, watchkit

I have designed my Watchkit app like that of a stopwatch.
In the screen I have WKInterfaceTimer * timer, Start Button, Stop Button, Reset Button and a Lap Button.

What I am trying to do is, when I press the "Lap" button the time that is displayed in the timer at the time of buttonPressAction should be stored in a variable.

How do I do this in the interfaceController.m ??? NOT in swift..

Comment: Please add the code you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly from the WatchKit docs (though I can't find it now), they said to start your own NSTimer in your WatchKit extension that will keep track of the same time as the `WKInterfaceTimer`.  Since you are doing laps you don't even need to do that.  Just set a member variable to `[NSDate date]` for when the lap starts and then when the user presses the lap button use `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:<DATE_AT_START_OF_LAP>]` to get the time interval for the lap and this is also the time interval for the start of the next lap.  So the start of the 1st lap is 0 and the start of the next lap will be the start of the previous lap plus the time interval for the current lap.  That will correspond to the time on your `WKInterfaceTimer`.